# Is there a way to retrieve an image and then display it in discord (discord bot)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, wolframalpha

I am relatively new at discordjs and web APIs, and I was dabbling around with the wolfram alpha API. I am trying to use the API as so: The user enters the query `!query 2+2`, and if it can be answered by the short answer API that wolfram offers, it returns that answer. If it cannot be answered by the short answer API, then it forwards it to the simple API (this API gives you an image) and it returns the link. However, discord can't easily convert the link into an image to show to the user, so I was wondering how I would convert the link passed by the wolfram API into an image that can immediately display on discord.

Here is the code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'question',
    description: 'get many questions answered using wolfram alpha',
    aliases: ['q'],
    cooldown: 3,
    async execute(message, args, d) {
        if (!args[0]) {return message.channel.send('whaddya want me to look up?');}
        let key = process.env.WOLFRAM;
        let wolfapi = `https://api.wolframalpha.com/v1/result?i=${encodeURIComponent(args.join(' '))}&appid=${key}`;
        let answer = await d.r2(wolfapi).text;
        if (answer === 'No short answer available') {
        let simpleWolf = `https://api.wolframalpha.com/v1/simple?i=${encodeURIComponent(args.join(' '))}&background=black&foreground=white&layout=labelbar&appid=${key}`
        return message.channel.send(simpleWolf);
        }
        message.channel.send(answer);
    }
};
```

If I could somehow do this with the r2 module (https://github.com/mikeal/r2) that would be cool too.

Comment: can you post an example for the link that the simple API returns?

Comment: Here is a simple API link example @Worthy Alpaca https://api.wolframalpha.com/v1/simple?i=tesla%20stocks&background=black&foreground=white&layout=labelbar&appid=W9QYK9-WXRP8Q6KWX

Comment: well, right now you are just calling a website. Have you tried making an actual API call to it?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying, I'm new to APIs so I don't know what that means

Comment: when you make an API call you essentially call a website like in a browser exept that you can send along request headers. For example you could send along a request to return data in a json format instead of something else. In this case doesn't make a difference because the API returns an image. With that you *could* set that as a picture in an embed for example.